# Группировка одного списка по значениям другого

Tags: python

Имеется два списка:

```
x = [1,2,1,3]
y = [4,7,3,6]
```

по результатам группировки первого списка:

```
from itertools import groupby

for k,g in groupby(x):
    group_x.append(list(g))

group_x = [[1,1],[2],[3]]
```

хотелось бы получить соответствующий группировке первого списка - второй список в виде:

```
group_y = [[4,3],[7],[6]]
```

Comment: А можете показать в вопросе как `group_x` получился? :)

Comment: А так, задача решается через сбор индексов, а не значений. Тогда, очень просто составить оба списка `group_*`

Comment: @gil9red, дополнил вопрос

Comment: @gil9red, не подскажите как это можно осуществить?

Comment: Пока в процессе, думаю через enumerate + groupby

Comment: у вас не получается `group_x = [[1,1],[2],[3]]` потому, что `groupby` группирует только подряд идущие одинаковые элементы

Comment: А вы точно весь код привели? Не должно было из `[1,2,1,3]` получиться `[[1,1],[2],[3]]` без предварительной сортировки `[1,2,1,3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

- Составляем новый список с указанием индекса элемента (`enumerate`)
- Сортируем список по элементам для возможности группировки (`sorted`). Для этого в функции сортировки обращаемся ко второму элементу, т.к. первый элемент будет хранить индекс
- Группируем список по элементам и оставляем в нем только индексы (`groupby`)
- Составляем новые списки по индексам

Код:

```
from itertools import groupby

x = [1,2,1,3]
y = [4,7,3,6]

spec_list = sorted(enumerate(x), key=lambda x: x[1])
group_index = [[i for i, v in g] for k, g in groupby(spec_list, key=lambda x: x[1])]
print(group_index)
# [[0, 2], [1], [3]]

group_x = [[x[i] for i in group] for group in group_index]
print(group_x)
# [[1, 1], [2], [3]]

group_y = [[y[i] for i in group] for group in group_index]
print(group_y)
# [[4, 3], [7], [6]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [1, 2, 1, 3]
y = [4, 7, 3, 6]


from itertools import groupby


only_first = lambda tpl: tpl[0]

z = sorted(zip(x, y), key=only_first)
group_z = []

for k,g in groupby(z, key=only_first):
    group_z.append(list(g))


group_y = [[tpl[1] for tpl in arr]
           for arr in group_z
           ]

print(group_y)
```